# Why cannot I delete a duplicate (and low in quality) post with answers while the other posts with my answers were deleted in the past?

Tags: support, deletion

I recently asked this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3833612/solve-for-x-8975-equiv-x-bmod-100) on MSE. Afterward, some community members found out that it was a duplicate question. Now, I also see that it's kind of a low-quality question, so wanted to delete it. But got the following pop-up:

---

[image]

---

(Also, can be seen somebody has already voted to delete)

And I don't understand why I cannot delete that post while some posts have been deleted which I posted answers to (below are some of them with many upvotes)

---

- [image]

---

- [image]

---

- [image]

---

Thanks for your thoughts in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You received two or more answers, in fact one positively scored answer would suffice, so you can't just delete your question. It now involves effort from other people, and that would be unfair to them.

That downgrades your delete vote to the same delete vote of every other user (moderators and SE employees excluded, of course). However you lack the privilege to vote for deleting a question, and therefore you cannot do it at all here.

Comment: Ok, I understand and respect the purpose of that red pop-up. But then why were my positively scored answers deleted? As far as I can remember, there were many answers, as well. I just want to understand this rule of MSE appropriately.

Comment: They were deleted by three votes cast by members of the site that have more than 10k points.

Comment: (For questions it's 10k, for answers it's 20k)